# CGAL Intersection Circle and Vertical Lines (not segments)

Tags: c++, computational-geometry, intersection, cgal

In CGAL I need to compute the exact intersection points between a set of lines and a set o circles. Starting from the circles (which can have irrational radius but rational squared_radius) I should compute the vertical line passing through the x_extremal_points of each circle (not segment but lines) and calculate the intersection point of each circle with each line.

I’m using CircularKernel and Circle_2 for the circles and Line_2 for the lines.
Here’s an example of how I compute the circles and the lines and how I check if they intersect.

```
int main()
{

    Point_2 a = Point_2(250.5, 98.5);
    Point_2 b = Point_2(156, 139);

    //Radius is half distance ab
    Circular_k::FT aRad = CGAL::squared_distance(a, b);

    Circle_2 circle_a = Circle_2(a, aRad/4);

    Circular_arc_point_2 a_left_point = CGAL::x_extremal_point(circle_a, false);
    Circular_arc_point_2 a_right_point = CGAL::x_extremal_point(circle_a, true);

    //for example use only left extremal point of circle a
    CGAL::Bbox_2 a_left_point_bb = a_left_point.bbox();

    Line_2 a_left_line = Line_2(Point_2(a_left_point_bb.xmin(), a_left_point_bb.ymin()),
                                Point_2(a_left_point_bb.xmin(), a_left_point_bb.ymax()));

    if ( do_intersect(a_left_line, circle_a) ) {
        std::cout << "intersect";
    }
    else {
        std::cout << " do not intersect ";
    }

    return 0;
}
```

This flow rises this exception:

```
CGAL error: precondition violation!
 Expression : y != 0
 File       : c:\dev\cgal-4.7\include\cgal\gmp\gmpq_type.h
 Line       : 371
 Explanation:
 Refer to the bug-reporting instructions at http://www.cgal.org/bug_report.html
```

I can’t figure out how I can calculate the intersection points.
Also, Is there a better way to compute the lines? I know abot the x_extremal_point function but it returns the Circular_arc_point point and I’m not able to construct a vertical line passing through them directly without using Bounding box.

Comment: I guess you cannot construct a line from a single point is what this is saying: `a_left_point_bb` is a degenerate box. What did you want to do? A vertical line through `a_left_point`?

Comment: oh! that's a degenerate box :/ ! Yes, I need a vertical line through a_left_point. Then I need to intersect it with all circles in set (in the example there is only circle_a) to get all interesection points. (kind of sweepline alg) using Line_2(Point_2(a_left_point_bb.xmin(), a_left_point_bb.ymin()), Point_2(a_left_point_bb.xmin(), 0)); it works. Is there a better way to compute it? how to get the intersection points?

Comment: you could instead directly use `Line_2(a_left_point, Point_2(a_left_point.x(), a_left_point.y() + 1))` avoiding the case where `a_left_point` has a y of `0`

Answer (score 0):

In your code, you seem to compute the intersection of a circle with the vertical line that passes through the extremal point of the circle (I forget the bounding box). Well, then the (double) intersection is the extremal point itself... 
More globally, you say in your text of introduction that you want to compute exact intersections. Then you should certainly not use bounding boxes, which by definition introduce some approximation.

If I understand your text correctly, 
* for testing the intersection of your vertical lines with the other circles, you don't need to construct the lines, you only need to compare the abscissae of the extremal points of two circles, which you can do with the CGAL circular kernel. 
* for computing the intersection of a vertical line that has non-rational coefficients (since its equation is of the form x= +-sqrt(r)) with another circle, then the CGAL circular kernel will not give you a pre-cooked solution. That kernel will help, but you must still compute a few things by hand. 
If you don't want to bother, then you can also just take a standard CGAL kernel with Core::Expr as underlying number type. It can do "anything", but it will be slower.

Comment: What I really need are the intersection intervals (on y-coordinate) between the vertical line and each circle. The vertical lines are computed starting from the extremal points of a circle (leftmost and rightmost) and intersection points between each pair of circles. Here I'm exposing the first step of my procedure, i.e. the computation of the vertical lines passing through extremal point. If with bounding box I lose precision, how can I get a vertical line that passes through a Circular_arc_point_2 a_left_point? thank you

Comment: That vertical line has equation x = x_a_left_point.  If you need the y-ranges, then as I said, you can compute everything you need with a (standard) CGAL kernel (e.g., CGAL::Cartesian) with Core::Expr.

Comment: and x_a_left_point = x_a +- sqrt(r_a).  This allows you to construct a line, see Line_2 in the CGAL kernel.

Answer (score 0):

For efficiency, you should look at the underlying 1D problem: projecting the lines and the circle on the X axis, you have a set of points and a set of intervals [Xc-R, Xc+R].

If the L points are sorted increasingly, you can locate the left bound of an interval in time Lg(L) by dichotomy, and scan the list of points until the right bound. This results in a O(Lg(L).C + I) behavior (C circle intervals), where I is the number of intersections reported.

I guess that with a merge-like process using an active list, if the interval bounds are also sorted you can lower to O(L + C + I).

The extension to 2D is elementary.